# controller not affecting the ionic app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i have been working on my first ionic app and am really confused as to why its not working. Its a simple login form. When the user inputs email and password, its suppose to validate it and take you to the home page and if the user clicks on signup instead, its suppose to take you to the sign up page. Unfortunately mine doesnt do anything, clicking the buttons has no effect and i cant work out why. also, when i added the controller, the title of the page "welcome" which was appearing before disappeared as well. i have no idea what im doing wrong. any help would be really appreciated. thanks!

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
<title></title>

<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
<link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>

<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="test">
<ion-pane>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</ion-pane>
</body>
</html>
```

welcome.html

```
 <ion-view title="Welcome" style="">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">

   <form name="loginForm" class="list" novalidate>

    <label class="item item-input">
    <input placeholder="Email" name="email" type="email" ng-model="email" required>
  </label>
  <p ng-show="e" name="errorE" ng-bind="errorE"></p>

  <label class="item item-input" name="password">
    <input placeholder="Password" type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" required>
  </label>
  <p ng-show="p" name="errorP" ng-bind="errorP"></p>
  <button class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="login(loginForm)">Login</button>
<p>Dont't have an account?</p>
<button class="button button-positive  button-block" ng-click="register()">Sign up!</button>
</form>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('test', ['ionic', 'test.controllers'])
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
  // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
  // for form inputs)
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);

  // Don't remove this line unless you know what you are doing. It stops the viewport
  // from snapping when text inputs are focused. Ionic handles this internally for
  // a much nicer keyboard experience.
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}

 });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('welcome', {
    url: '/welcome',
    templateUrl: 'template/welcome.html',
    controller: 'WelcomeController'
})
.state('register', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'template/register.html'
    //, controller: 'RegisterController'
})
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'template/home.html'
    //,controller: 'HomeController'
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/welcome');
});
```

controllers.js

```
angular.module('test.controllers', [])
.controller('welcomeController', function ($scope) {
$scope.email = '';
$scope.password = '';
$scope.errorE="";
$scope.errorP="";
$scope.errorM1="Email not valid";
$scope.errorM2="Password required";
$scope.e=false;
$scope.p=false;

$scope.login=function(form)
{
if(form.$valid) 
{
  $scope.errorP="perfect";
  $scope.errorE="perfect";
  $scope.e=true;
  $scope.p=true;
  $state.go('home');
}
else
{
   if(form.email.$invalid || form.email.$pristine)
    {
    $scope.errorE=$scope.errorM1;
    $scope.e=true;
    }
    else
    {
    $scope.e=false;
    }

    if(form.password.$invalid || form.password.$pristine)
    {
    $scope.errorP=$scope.errorM2;
    $scope.p=true;
    }
    else
    {
     $scope.p=false;
    }
}

}

 $scope.register = function() {
  $state.go('register');
 }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are three problems

1

the ionic.bundle.js already bring angular

2 "WelcomeController" angular/javascript is case sensitive

3 you forget to inject **$state** in "WelcomeController"

Comment: I am happy to help.